# XAML Datagrid not updating binding when container closes

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, propertychanged, updatesourcetrigger

I have a WPF User Control with a datagrid sitting within a WinForms form. The datagrid is bound to a datasource using the ItemsSource binding. It all works fine so when data is changed the changes propogate to the object model.

However, if the user is editing data in the datagrid and then clicks on the Close button of the hosting container then the datagrid doesn't update the binding, presumably because it doesn't think it's lost focus. The form closes and the changes are lost.

The same problem is also true for text boxes but I can get around that by using the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged so that the underlying model is constantly being updated as the text changes. Not ideal - but it avoids the problem.

Does anyone know how to either switch the datagrid into PropertyChanged mode for updating the source, or do something to force the datagrid to save the changes through the binding to the underlying object?

While researching this I found this article helpful: http://www.jerryhuang.net/post/Force-a-data-binding-to-update.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Did you try calling CommitEdit on DataGrid before closing the container?

Comment: Thanks using myGrid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, True) has saved the changes. It still seems a bit clunky as I have to name the datagrid, set up a method in the code behind (I didn't have any code behind before), then make sure the hosting application calls the method on the user control. It doesn't feel very MVVM! But my app works now even if it doesn't feel elegant.

Comment: If you want everything in xaml, perhaps defining 'EditingElementStyle' and setting UpdateSourceTrigger on binding object is the way.